# Find $\|\cdot\|_2$ norm of block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices, matrix-norms, toeplitz-matrices

> Compute the square norm $\|\cdot\|_2$ of the following block matrix
>   \begin{bmatrix}
>      O & I_n & \dots  & O \\
>      I_n & O & \ddots  & O \\
>      \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & I_n \\
>      O & O & I_n  & O
> \end{bmatrix} 
>   where $I_n$ is the identity matrix of order $n$.

I have no idea to find norm of the above block matrix. Can anyone give me a hint? Thank you in advance !

Comment: What norm are you using? Can you do the case $n = 1$?

Comment: I want to find square norm. Otherwise it would be very easy. I has no idea for the case n = 1.

Comment: What is "square norm"? You mean the operator norm induced from the usual, Euclidean, norm?

Comment: Yes, $||(x_1,\ldots,x_n)|| = \sqrt{x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2}$

Comment: That doesn't make sense. We are talking about matrix norms, not vector norms. Your matrix has $n^4$ entries. What do you mean by $\sqrt{x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2}$?

Comment: If you are talking about the *induced* 2-norm (i.e. the operator norm, a.k.a. spectral norm), the following fact is useful: [the eigenvalues of an $n\times n$ tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix](https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=I-anVsXuN9eF1ASl_5CQCw#safe=off&q=tridiagonal+toeplitz+matrix+eigenvalues) are given by $\lambda_j = a+2\sqrt{bc}\cos\frac{j\pi}{n+1};\,j=1,2,\ldots,n$ (where the main diagonal entries are equal to $a$, and $b,c$ are the values of the entries of the other two diagonals).

Comment: @user1551 link you sent is dead

Comment: @DavidLi Just google "tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix eigenvalues" and click any relevant link.

Comment: It is somewhat ambiguous what matrix you are describing.  A few more block entries in the expression would help Readers to distinguish between the block tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix and the block permutation matrix (blocks $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & I \\ I & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ along the diagonal).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\|{#1}\right\|}$
First of all you have to know or demonstrate that

$$\norm{S \otimes T} \leq \norm{S}\norm{T}$$

Then notice that the matrix $M$ you address is

$$M=J \otimes I$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix and $J$ the generalization of this matrix
$$J = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
\end{array}\right ]$$
then you have

$$\norm{J \otimes I} \leq \norm{J}\norm{I}$$
i.e.
$$\norm{J \otimes I} \leq \norm{J}$$

Now you have to find the norm of J. There could be an easier way, but I'm not seeing other thing that diagonalize the matrix which is symmetric.

I would consider the characteristic polynomial. Considering the resolvant matrix:
$$J- \lambda I = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
\lambda & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & \lambda & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & \lambda & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & \lambda\\ 
\end{array}\right ]$$

which is ruled by the following succession (cfr. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix):
$$ p_0(\lambda)=1 $$
$$ p_1(\lambda)=\lambda $$
$$ p_n(\lambda)=\lambda p_{n-1}-p_{n-2} $$

So for every $n$ you can find the eigenvalues you need to diagonalize and then get the max which is your norm.
Being more specific as user1551 pointed out this is a special kind of tridiagonal Toeplitz Matrix and the eigen values are given by 
$$ \lambda_k=2 \cos(k \pi)/ (n+1) $$
with $k=1..n$ so I guess you also have an explicit formula for your norm.

Comment: No...I was just saying $\| J\|_2^2=2$ to avoid the use of squareroot

Comment: Hi @Dac0, is $||J|| = \sqrt{2}$ correct? For example if $n = 4$. I check that $||J|| = $ maximal value of absolute eigenvalues of matrix J that is $1.61803 \neq \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: And here for the case n=5
 https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvalues+%7B%7B0%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C0%7D%7D

Comment: @DavidLi Dac0 is probably trying an example with $n=3$.

Comment: Sorry I considered a bad J I'll try to fix it