# Compute the square norm $||\cdot||_2$ of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

> Compute the square norm $||\cdot||_2$ of matrix :
>   \begin{bmatrix}
>      O & A_n^{-1} & \dots  & O \\
>      A_n^{-1} & O & \ddots  &  \\
>      \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & A_n^{-1} \\
>      O & O & A_n^{-1}  & O
> \end{bmatrix} 
>   where $A_n^{-1}$ is the inverse of matrix $A_n$ of order $n$. 
>   $$A_n =\begin{bmatrix}
>      4 & -1 & \dots  & O \\
>      -1 & 4 & \ddots  &  \\
>      \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & -1 \\
>      O & O & -1  & 4
> \end{bmatrix}$$

I am unable to find norm of the above matrix. Can anyone give me a hint? Thank you in advance !

Comment: As the OP had posted [a very similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1627640/find-cdot-2-norm-of-block-matrix) a few hours ago, I voted to close this question.

Comment: The answer in that post is NOT correct and my question in this post is different. Please see my comment. Thamks

Comment: Thanks, David. If the answer given in the other thread is incorret, it's mainly because your definition (if any) of "square norm" is unclear. Anyway, I don't see there're any fundamental differences between the questions, so I think this question should still be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your large matrix is also symmetric, so computing the 2-norm is a question of computing the eigenvalues. I recommend that you write your large matrix as a Kronecker product $E \otimes A^{-1}$ for a suitable symmetric matrix $E$. Known properties of the Kronecker product will then solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks. But I am unable to find the eigenvalues of two Kronecker matrices E and $A_n^{-1}$

Comment: Then the best hint I can give is to study the eigenvalues of the discrete Laplacian matrix. Both your matrices are closely related to this matrix.

Comment: Thank you. I could not find anything useful on Internet for your suggestion.

Comment: Try searching for the string "eigenvalues discrete laplacian" or experiment with vectors $x$ of the type $x_j = \sin(j\theta)$ for suitable values of $\theta$

Answer (score 2):

As Carl Christen said you just need to find the eigenvalues of your $A^{-1}_n$ and get the max.
The characteristic polynomial of $A^{-1}_n$ is:

$$ p_0(\lambda)=1$$
$$ p_1(\lambda)=\lambda - 4 $$
$$ ... $$
$$ p_n(\lambda)=(\lambda - 4) p_{n-1} + p_{n-2} $$
Being the resolvant a tridiagonal matrix of the form
$$A^{-1}_n- \lambda I = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
\lambda -4 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
-1 & \lambda - 4& -1 & 0\\
0 & -1 & \lambda -4 & -1\\
0 & 0 & -1 & \lambda -4\\ 
\end{array}\right ]$$
Anyway being $A^{-1}_n$ a tridiagonal toeplizt matrix as user1551 pointed out, the eigenvalues are easily computed (cfr. http://www.math.kent.edu/~reichel/publications/toep3.pdf) being:
$$ \lambda_k=4+2 cos(k \pi)/ (n+1) $$
with $k=1..n$. Take the max and there you have your norm.

Answer (score 0):

Call your big matrix $B$. $\|B\|_2^2$ is just the sum of squares of all entries. So, if you find $\left\|A_n^{-1}\right\|_2^2 = x$, and notice your large matrix has exactly $2(n-1)$ copies of $A_n^{-1}$, so
$$
\|B\|_2^2 = 2(n-1)x...
$$

Comment: Hi @gt6989b, thanks but square norm you mentioned is not what I want to find.